# MVC ASP.NET - Unit Test with MOQ for User.Identity.Name in Custom HTML Helper

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Experts I've a simple HTML Helper method below. Could anyone tell me how to mock the user.identity.name on this scenario:

```
public static string GetLoggedUsername(this HtmlHelper helper)
{
    return repo.Name + " - [" + HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name + "]";
}
```

> I'm facing object reference not
>   set.... error

I don't know how to pass user.identity.name while unit testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Replace `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` with `helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name`.

You will then create an instance of HtmlHelper in your unit test and mock out its dependencies. Then pass in the HtmlHelper instance as a parameter in your helper function, like so:

```
        var mockViewContext = new Mock<ViewContext>();
        mockViewContext.Setup(x => x.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name).Returns("TheUser");

        var mockViewDataContainer = new Mock<IViewDataContainer>();

        var helper = new HtmlHelper(mockViewContext.Object, mockViewDataContainer.Object);

        var output = GetLoggedUsername(helper);

        Assert.AreEqual("RepoName - [TheUser]", output);
```

Comment: Thank you John It worked. I will appreciate if you could help me with these queries please. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769163/asp-net-mvc-unit-testing-override-initialize-method. And also this one if you don't mind http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767640/moq-setup-vs-setupget